# Headphones vibrate annoyingly with bass?

Tags: headphones, bass

I got these headphones a while ago, and they were cheap, so I was expecting problems, but listen to music with a lot of bass has become hard, as every time I do, I get a small vibration in one of the speakers in the left ear. It has become gradually louder to the point where I'm getting headaches. This happens when the music is very quiet too, so I know that isn't the problem.

I tried reducing the bass on my iPod, and that worked, but I have no idea what has caused the problem, I mean, the foam on the speakers is stuck on by glue, so maybe the glue is covering one of the speakers? I'm not a sound expert and I just found this website, please help!

Comment: Simplest explanation is the voice-coil is distorted, effectively causing it to hit the sides of the magnet when it's moving. Cheap headphones, cheap solution; throw them away.

Comment: Maybe the the headphone speaker membrane broke also.